# c++ delay printf until needed

Tags: c++, buffer, printf

In c++, Is it possible to write to some kind of buffer with printf (or similar) and then later in the program either write the buffer to the screen or discard it depending on the outcome.

I want to do this because I have a recursive function and only want the see the things printed throughout the recursion if the result is of interest.

Comment: no. but you can print to a buffer with spintf, and print it with printf only when/if needed

Comment: Why cant you use a conditional statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. You can leverage the power of `vsnprintf` for that purpose. I'd suggest some sort of class wrapping an `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` (essentially the same in C++11):

```
#include <cstdargs>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

class Formatter
{
    std::string buf;
public:
    void add(char const * fmt, ...)
    {
        std::va_list ap, aq;
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        va_copy(aq, ap);

        int ret1 = std::vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap);
        // check ret1 != -1

        std::size_t cur = buf.size();
        buf.resize(cur + ret1 + 1);

        int ret2 = std::vsnprintf(&buf[cur], ret1 + 1, fmt, aq);
        // check ret2 != -1
        buf.resize(cur + ret1);

        va_end(aq);
        va_end(ap);
    }

    std::string const & str() const { return buf; }
};
```

Now you can say:

```
Formatter f;
f.add("Hello, %s", "world");
f.add("%i%i%i", 1, 2, 3);
std::cout << f.str() << std::endl;
```

If you're very concerned about performance, you can try and preallocate some space for the print operation and maintain a separate "end" position, in the hope that you'll never have to run the `vnsprintf` call more than once.

Comment: I like the look of this method but can't find the right includes to use

Comment: You need `<cstdargs>`, `<cstdio>, and `<string>`. I'll edit it.

Comment: Got it, my mistake, I already had these but didn't notice the error saying invalid compiler directive #includ (I forgot the E), this works great, I also added a clear function that just does buf="";

Comment: @DanJAB: or `buf.clear()` :-) (Or `std::string().swap(buf);` if you want to shrink the memory usage, which may actually be a *bad* idea.)

Comment: Is it possible to have newlines in the buffer? how do I add them f.add("\n"); seems to not do anything.

Comment: @DanJAB: Yeah, that should work. What makes you believe it doesn't?

Comment: @DanJAB: Sorry, there was a bug, the second list should have been `aq`.

Comment: I still can't get \n to move to a new line

Comment: GOT IT, the last character is never added. the n in \n was always the last character.

Comment: @DanJAB: Oh crap, you're right: You need to give `vsnprintf` enough space to include the trailing zero! Let me fix that. (I have a similar, yet different version of this class for my own use which *does* emit the trailing zero, so I confused myself.)

Answer (score 4):

The class `std::ostringstream` is what you are looking for.

In C++, formatted IO is done (preferably) through the `<iostream>` library. This is the famous `cout << variable << endl`.

`cout` outputs directly to the standard output. If you want to buffer instead, you can redirect your output to a `std::ostringstream` instance that you can later redirect to the standard out:

```
#include <iostream>

[...]


ostringstream buf;
buf << myVar1 << "MyStr" << endl;

[...] // some time later

cout << buf.str();
```

If you prefer the `printf` way of doing things, you can use `sprintf` (though I won't recommend it). It's a bit more complex because you need to know the size of the buffer in advance.

```
char myBuf[10000]; // up to you do to the proper bound checking
sprintf(myBuf, "format %d", myvar);

[...] // you may want to use strcat and such for more complex operations

printf(myBuf);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is about using a string ?
Or a string array. Or a collection ?
Gathering all data u need and printing if needed ?

Comment: I thought that those questions imply an answer?

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a class that already exists that is a buffer that has a printf function (like the one used to put text on the screen) and another to put the whole block on the screen in bulk at the end.

Comment: you can use strcat to "add" buffers/strings. or just use "+" with std::string

Comment: Ok let's assume you wanna validate something. And therefore you have a string you write data to. Every loop you concatenate/add new data to the string. and in the end depending on the result you can print the string. This is what you want, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sprintf` function which does the same thing as `printf` into char buffer. But you shall not. These old C-style functions are obsolete in C++, you shall use streams instead. Looks like `std::stringstream` fit you needs.

Answer (score 0):

For a recursing function, the best way would be to delay *getting the result*, not printing it, so instead of this:

```
int fact( int n )
{
    printf("%d", n);
    if( n!=1 )
        return n * fact(n - 1);
    else return 1;
};
<....>
fact( 5 );
```

you might use this:

```
int fact( int n )
{
    if( n!=1 )
        return n * fact(n - 1);
    else return 1;
};
<....>
int result = fact( 5 );
printf("%d", result);
```

Basically, print it only when it's ready. If for some reasons you can't do it directly, save the result into some kind of a buffer variable, and access it after the function ends.

Comment: This is fine for most uses but this is is an almost random recursion the produces many valid results